# mex file debugging with Eclipse ubuntu 12.04

Tags: eclipse, matlab, ubuntu

I am new to Linux (Ubuntu-12.04) and trying to debug mex file using eclipse as per the way provided by Torstein in

[Is it possible to debug mex code with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471276/is-it-possible-to-debug-mex-code-with-eclipse)

I am getting following messages on Console {Console(Matlab [c/c++ application]gdb)} and unable to execute 7th step provided in above post.

`No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command`.

`No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.`

`No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.`

`No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.`
Function "main" not defined.

`[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]`

`Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1"`.

`[New Thread 0x7fffe34f0700 (LWP 12435)] .......`

I looked extensively on Internet, but I unable to get proper answer. Anyone knows how to fix it ?