# how to stop exection in eclipse when a condition is met

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, debugging, memory

I have a global counter variable in c projet.

It increase out of desired bounds,

but i cannot find the line of the increase.

Is there any way to hold execution on the line where this variable is above `X` ?

I can get the variable memory address.

Comment: Normally you will have just a few lines where that variable gets increased. If not, consider encapsulating it and provide some access functions. Widely used globals are a mess to work with. Some compilers provide the possibility to place memory breakpoints that get triggered when the data at a certain address is altered.

Comment: `Some compilers provide the possibility to place memory breakpoints that get triggered when the data at a certain address is altered.` does gcc in eclipse does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few minutes of googling confirmed what I suggested in my comment:

GDB, which is the debugger for GCC, supports so-called *watchpoints*.

You can find a description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851/can-i-set-a-breakpoint-on-memory-access-in-gdb), how to set them in GDB's command line. You can toggle those watchpoints in Eclipse as well (supposedly depends on the Eclipse version you are using). [This blog post](http://www.fayewilliams.com/2013/02/19/eclipse-cdt-toggle-watchpoint-greyed-out-juno/) tells you how to do it.

If you haven't installed GDB (I wonder what your debugger would be then), [there is a SO post covering the installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544711/how-to-install-gdb-debugger-to-eclipse-cdt).

Answer (score 0):

If it is global and you do not have any idea how it is increasing, hit ctrl + h, search for the variable name and see where it is being f-ed up. Probably something else somewhere modifies it and you don't have any clue about it. Overall using globals is a very bad idea. The best way to monitor it is to use some procedure which is the only one who can access your counter and then in that function compare it with X.

Comment: I agree, but it's a lagacey huge code and I don't have the time to refactor ATM. I have tried to ctrl+h it and so many instances. Isn't there a built-in way to pause on a condition in eclipse?

Comment: the hard thing is that is can be assignment to another pointer and there along the way an increment under another name.